# unable to connect to mysql socket from C program

Tags: mysql, c, macos, sockets, connection

I am developing a C program that accesses mysql.  I have the following line in my code:

```
sts = connect_to_server(&mysql, "localhost", "my_username",
            "my_password, "my_databasename");
```

with the actual values replaced, of course. I get:

> Failed to connect to MySQL: Error: Can't connect to local MySQL server
>   through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)

I have seen other questions like this, and the answer is usually that the server is down.  In this case it is not.  PHPMyAdmin can access the server just fine.

And many of the other responses said to check for the socket file.  It is present

```
(/Applications/AMPPS/mysql/tmp/mysql.sock).
```

Could this be something to do with paths or something?  It isn't adding the path to "`/temp/mysql.sock`" and therefore can't find it?

I know very little about unix.  I have been running OSX for nearly 10 years, but I almost never go down to that level.

Comment: `/Applications/AMPPS/mysql/tmp/mysql.sock` != `/tmp/mysql.sock`

Comment: I know.  I am not specifying the abbreviated path.  The library routine is.  I am asking how to tell it the rest of the path.  I tried environmental variables and adding it to the PATH itself.  No effect.

Comment: restart MySQL server check for any errors in the log.

Comment: Where does `connect_to_server()` come from?

Comment: Turns out that connect_to_server() was not passing the socket name to mysql_real_connect().  The guy who wrote it only intended to use the port and had NULL for the socket name.  Duh.  Sorry for the annoyance. I would have expected mysql_real_connect to look at the CNF file, but apparently it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look into the mysql configuration file (typical `my.cnt` somehwhere under `/etc`) and adjust the value for `socket` to fit your needs.

Alternativly you could just link `/tmp/mysql.sock` to `/Applications/AMPPS/mysql/tmp/mysql.sock`:

```
ln -s /Applications/AMPPS/mysql/tmp/mysql.sock /tmp/mysql.sock
```

Answer (score 0):

I think wrong my.ini is getting loaded. By default it looks at /etc/my.ini so if it is present just rename or delete it. Restart your MySQL Server.